# Setting up remote execution of Coded UI Tests Via Visual studio online

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops, coded-ui-tests

I have a coded UI test Solution. Till now I used to run test cases on agent machine via MTM. Now I want to run test cases on agent via visual studio online.
When I am trying to run through visual studio online, I am not able to see any build as you can see in the screeshot below.

[image]

I used to create XAML build for my test execution via MTM. I don't know what I have to do. 
Please Can anyone help.

Additional Info : When I go to builds tab in visual studio online I do see XAML build definitions under XAML tab.

Comment: Have you clicked the **Find** button? If you didn't trigger the find, no builds will be displayed there.

Comment: yes I did click on find button.

Comment: The xmal build controller is not supported now. You need to Migrate from XAML builds to new builds (vNext builds), I can see the vNext builds on my side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xmal build controller is not supported now. You need to configure your own build controller and agent to build your xaml build definitions. For more details, please refer to [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2017/05/30/evolving-tfsteam-services-build-automation-capabilities/). I'd recommend migrating to the new builds system (vNext builds). See [Migrate from XAML builds to new builds](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/build-release/actions/migrate-from-xaml-builds).

To run the Coded UI Tests Via Visual studio online, you have to configure the private test agent to interact with the Desktop and build agent running as **interactive Mode**. See [Deploy an agent on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-windows).

Then you can use **[Run Functional Tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/test/run-functional-tests)** task to run Automated Test on agent machine. See [Running Automated Test on agent machine using vNext Build](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2016/08/05/running-automated-test-on-agent-machine-using-vnext-build/) for details.

Related thread: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/148614/we-deprecated-the-hosted-xaml-build-controller.html

---

**UPDATE:**

To run test cases using solution, you need to build the test solution first  (Add a build step), then run test with **Run Functional Tests** task. See [Run unit tests with your builds](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/build-release/test/getting-started-with-continuous-testing) for details. With **Run Functional Tests** task, you can execute Automated tests in Build vNext using Test Plan, Test Suites. Please refer to below link for details. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/03/31/executing-automated-tests-in-build-vnext-using-test-plan-test-suites/

If you mean Test Case work item, then you need to link test cases to test methods with MTM or Visual Studio.Then run the test in Test Hub. See [Associate automated tests with test cases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/test/associate-automated-test-with-test-case).

You may also want to [Run automated tests from test plans in the Test hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/build-release/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub).

Comment: @Pankaj Devrani Have you resolved the issue? Is that helpful for you? any update?

Comment: Yes It was helpful but not totally.
I have a coded UI test Solution in my TFS server and I want to run test cases using that solution. Can you tell how can I trigger my test cases from the test plans online using agent pool(name= abc).

Comment: but if I add test task to my build. will this will run all the test during the build queue? if yes then I don't want to do that because there are more then 100 test cases are there in my solution if one test fail it will fail the build.

Comment: @PankajDevrani Have you checked [the link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/03/31/executing-automated-tests-in-build-vnext-using-test-plan-test-suites/) I provided above? Choose the Test Plan from which you want to run your tests. You can then select one or more test suites from a Tree view control followed by a Test Configuration. So you can manage the tests by the test plan.

Comment: I did checked your link. What I am trying to do is create build first and then test later. Is it possible that I build first and then I can run my test case by going to testhub > test plan > test suite and then choose whatever test case I want and right click and go to run option and choose the build and environment then run. The way I used to do in MTM.

Comment: @PankajDevrani Yes, you can, another point just as I mentioned in the updated answer, you can create test case work item and  [Associate automated tests with test cases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/test/associate-automated-test-with-test-case). Then run the test cases with options from the test plan as the image you posted in your question.

Comment: this is the error message I am getting while deploying the release definition : System.InvalidOperationException: No test assemblies found on the test machine matching the source filter criteria or no tests discovered matching test filter criteria. Verify that test assemblies are present on the machine and test filter criteria is correct.                 " Although I am running the test case task by using test plan".

Comment: @PankajDevrani The error message is very clear "`No test assemblies found on the test machine`", you need the the test binaries. Please follow the steps mentioned in this link [Run automated tests from test plans in the Test hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/build-release/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub).

Comment: I have added the test plan with with one test case in it. I have also attached test script with the test case in MTM through Visual studio. I run those test cases in MTM lab environment via XAML build of same solution. I don't know why it is now able to find the test case.

Comment: Yes I am able to create new build successfully now. And it ishttps://stackoverflow.com/users/7466674/andy-li-msft also able to find the test cases in it. Problem was with test assembly filter, which I was not able to use properly. Thank you for your help @Andy Li-MSFT  . I really appreciate it.

Comment: One last question I have. When i am deploying the release definition, it is running all the test casaes present in. But I don't want to run any test case at that time. All I want to do is deploy the release definition without running any test case and run test cases later by going to test> test plans>test suite and click on run option and run the test cases. Is it possible to do?

Comment: @PankajDevrani No, you have to get test assemblies first to run the tests. If you want to run the tests separately, then you have to copy the  test assemblies (built in build or release process) to a specific location which can be found by the test runner.

Comment: I have copied test assemblies to a specific location (drop). But how can I use them so that my test runner finds them to run test?